# Wifi Adaptor Not Found - Acer Laptop ubuntu 22.04.3 Wifi 6Ax101

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, laptop, acer

I am using Acer Laptop AL15-52 which was by default in Windows 11 Home SL OS. I changed the Operating System to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. After that I couldn't see the Wi-Fi Symbol in the Ubuntu.

I am facing this issue in Ubuntu only, the wifi worked in Default Windows 11 OS

When I searched for Wi-Fi in settings there it displayed "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found. Make sure you have a Wi-Fi Adapter plugged and turned on". The command "lscpi" shows Network Controller: Intel Wireless .. Connection" But the Additional Drivers is not listing any propriety drivers to install.

Please let me know some solution to fix this

Comment: please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; sudo dmesg| grep iwl|tail -20`

Comment: Can you put Ubuntu 23.10 on a USB and see if wifi works there?